# set value on label of child view from parent view

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have been setting the values from parent view to child view where I create the object of child. Like follows:

```
-(void)pushView  
{  
  spikeyDetectionAddDrugVC *myVC = [[spikeyDetectionAddDrugVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"spikeyDetectionAddDrugVC" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES]; 
  myVC.lblHeaderTitle.Text = @"From here";  
}
```

this following line:

```
myVC.lblHeaderTitle.Text = @"From here";
```

does not work.
It does not set the text on child view unless we forward something view object.

Is there any new way to set this in ios7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not even Objective-C. Message sent to objects are enclosed in square brackets. The language is case sensitive, so you have to use the proper attribute of a `UILabe` which is `text`, not `Text`.

Comment: Yes I know I just wrote the sudo code to ask the question.